# Printing out symbols into tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I need to write a code using a function, that counts all symbols into dictionary (including whitespace, commas etc) and another function to print all elements that accoured atleast once into tuple (i.e giving "Hello world" output=('h', 'e', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'r', 'd') This is my code so far:

```
def frequency(word):
  dict = {}
  for el in word:
     el = el.lower()
     if el in dict and not "":
         dict[el] += 1
     elif el not in dict and not "":
         dict[el] = 1
  for k,v in dict.items():
    print(k + ":" + str(v))

def different_symbols(word):
  dict={}
  for el in dict:
      if el not in dict:
          dict[el] = el
      elif el in dict:
         print(el)

frequency("Hello world!")
different_symbols("Hello world!")
```

Comment: If you're not concerned about order, you could just do `set(word)`

Comment: At least this OP did write some code..

Comment: @mangohero. Where I should use set?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis They don't have a question.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Thank you! I try to work out by myself, but when I get stuck I ask with done work

Comment: @MartinSuits Can you please clearly state what the problem you are facing is?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis it counts normal like h:1, e:1, but in column. I need both outputs in list. Like this:
h:1
e:1
l:3
o:2
 :1
w:1
r:1
d:1
!:1
l
o
l

Comment: @Mangohero1 You're the man!! Thanks, bro!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Measure frequency using `Counter.most_common()` and unique characters with `set()`. If you specifically want `dict` and `tuple` type results:

```
from collections import Counter

def frequency(word):
    letters = Counter(word).most_common()
    letters_dict = {k: v for k, v in letters}
    return letters_dict

def different_symbols(word):
    return tuple(set(word))

print(frequency("Hello World!"))
# {'l': 3, 'o': 2, 'H': 1, 'e': 1, ' ': 1, 'w': 1, 'r': 1, 'd': 1}

print(different_symbols("Hello World!"))
# ('d', ' ', 'r', 'l', 'H', 'e', 'o', 'w') order is completely random
```